# Prove that every interval is in one of these 9 forms

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that we define an interval in this way :

A set with members in $\mathbb R$ is called an interval iff $S$ has at least two members and for each pair $x,y \in S$ , every real number like $x \lt z \lt y$ , $z \in S$.

Theorem :
Every Interval is in one of these forms :
1.  $(a,b)=\{x \in \mathbb R: a \lt x \lt b \}$
2.  $[a,b)=\{x \in \mathbb R: a \le x \lt b \}$
3.  $(a,b]=\{x \in \mathbb R: a \lt x \le b \}$
4.  $[a,b]=\{x \in \mathbb R: a \le x \le b \}$
5.  $(- \infty,a)=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \lt a \}$
6.  $(- \infty,a]=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \le a \}$
7.  $(b,\infty)=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \gt b \}$
8.  $[b,\infty)=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \ge b \}$
9.  $(-\infty,\infty)=\mathbb R$

Note 1: This question is taken from a book named "Real analysis: A first course" written by Russel Gordon.  The question itself tells that consider some cases, like "If $S$ has upper bound","If $S$ is bounded", and so on. But i don't get the point.

Note 2 :  I have no idea how to prove this kind of theorem.  "Being in some form" seems not accurate enough to me. How should i prove it ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three possibilities for the greatest lower bound (or infimum) of the set $S:$

1. It doesn't exist.
2. It exists and it belongs to $S.$
3. It exists and it doesn't belong to $S.$

Similarly, there are three possibilities for the least upper bound (or supremum) of the set $S.$

Since you can match any of the $3$ possibilites for the g.l.b. with any of the $3$ possibilities for the l.u.b., there are $3\cdot 3=9$ possibilities total.  Each one corresponds to one of the possibilities you listed.

Comment: Thank you sir :) I totally understood what you wrote...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Look at $\sup(S)$ and $\inf(S)$, they will give you the $a$ and $b$.

Discuss what happens if one or both is/are $\pm \infty$. If both are real numbers, discuss what happens if they belong or not in $S$.

Comment: I was told that nothing can be equal to $\infty$. So, how should i consider suprimum or infimum equals to $\infty$ ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Saying $\sup S$ is $\infty$ is shorthand for saying $S$ is not upper bounded.

Comment: As egreg said, if you are not familiar with the notation, whenever when I say $\pm infty$ read it us unbounded above/below.....